# Simplify the timeline in SQL(Netezza)

Tags: mysql, sql, netezza

I want to summarize/simplify(I don't know what to call) my timeline.

So what I have are the ID with the timeline. I am trying to get rid of the overlap timeline within the same id.

Here are the example of the data.
What I have:

```
ID   START_TIME   END_TIME
 1        a          b
 1        c          d
 1        e          f
 1        g          h
```

[image]
As you can see from the picture, `[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]` overlap each other and `[g,h]` are disjoint so I just want `[a,f]` and `[g,h]`. 
What I want:

```
ID   START_TIME   END_TIME
 1        a          f
 1        g          h
```

Comment: @shA.t can you give me some example of the overlap/disjoint column?

Answer (score 1):

I think @shA.T is close.  The problem is in multiple overlaps this would break down.  You might have to turn this into a multiple step process

Step 1 (Make Sample Table):

```
 create temp table stack (
 id integer
 ,start_time timestamp
 ,end_time timestamp
 )

 insert into stack  values(1, date('2020-01-01'),date('2020-01-01') + interval '3 hours');
 insert into stack  values(1,date('2020-01-01') + interval '2 hours',date('2020-01-01') + interval '4 hours');
 insert into stack  values(1,date('2020-01-01') + interval '3.5 hours',date('2020-01-01') + interval '5 hours');
 insert into stack  values(1,date('2020-01-01') + interval '5.5 hours',date('2020-01-01') + interval '6.5 hours');
 insert into stack  values(1,date('2020-01-01') + interval '7.5 hours',date('2020-01-01') + interval '9.5 hours');
 insert into stack  values(1,date('2020-01-01') + interval '8.5 hours',date('2020-01-01') + interval '10.5 hours');
```

Step 2 (Find single overlaps):

```
create temp table stack2 as
 SELECT ID, ps2 as start_time, max(e) AS End_Time
    FROM (
        SELECT t1.ID, t1.START_TIME AS s, MAX(t1.END_TIME) AS e,
               max(t2.START_TIME) As ps, MAX(t2.END_TIME) AS pe
               ,CASE WHEN pe between s and e THEN ps ELSE s END ps2
        FROM stack AS t1
        JOIN stack AS t2 ON t1.START_TIME > t2.START_TIME
        GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.START_TIME) AS DT
    GROUP BY
        ID, ps2
    ORDER BY ps2
```

Step 3 (Consolidate Double Overlaps):

```
 SELECT ID, ps2 as start_time, max(e) AS End_Time
    FROM (
        SELECT t1.ID, t1.START_TIME AS s, MAX(t1.END_TIME) AS e,
               max(t2.START_TIME) As ps, MAX(t2.END_TIME) AS pe
               ,CASE WHEN pe between s and e THEN ps ELSE s END ps2
        FROM stack2 AS t1
        JOIN stack2 AS t2 ON t1.START_TIME > t2.START_TIME
        GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.START_TIME) AS DT
    GROUP BY
        ID, ps2
    ORDER BY ps2
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution without adding any additional column like this:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(CASE WHEN pe between s and e THEN ps ELSE s END) AS START_TIME, MAX(e) AS End_Time
FROM (
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.START_TIME AS s, t1.END_TIME AS e, 
           MAX(t2.START_TIME) As ps, MAX(t2.END_TIME) AS pe
    FROM t AS t1
    JOIN t AS t2 ON t1.START_TIME > t2.START_TIME
    GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.START_TIME, t1.END_TIME ) AS DT
GROUP BY
    ID, CASE WHEN pe between s and e THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
ORDER BY s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but it seems like it needs some tweaking. Do you mind explaining what does 'CASE WHEN pe between s and e THEN 1 ELSE 0 END' in GROUP BY statement do?

Comment: @devon It is that *extra overlap/disjoint column* that means when a previous end-time (`pe`) is between duration of current task (`between s and e`) it is a new group ;).